# Error encountered moving TFS2010 to a new server

Tags: windows-server-2008, installation, migration, team-foundation-server

I'm attempting do a test move of our TFS2010 server and I'm encountering an error. I've got a new Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server installation as on the current server and I've turned off the services and backed up the databases on the old one. All processes running as the same account as the previous server.

I've then restored the databases on the new server and I'm attempting to run the "Application-Tier Only" wizard as the documentation suggests. A I'm expecting to be able to select the tfs_configuration database but the error message I get is:

*"TFS254006: No usable accounts are present in your configuration database. Use TfsConfig accounts /add to add an account and return to this wizard."*

Obviously I can't use the TfsConfig tool on this server because I haven't set it up yet, I could use the tool from the old server but that doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Chris,

Sounds like you're trying to move (both AT and data tier) to new hardware? If so, here is the [topic on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx

You're about halfway through the steps already. Instead of running the AT only wizard, install TFS using either the standard or advanced wizards.

Once that's done, there are some command line tools you have to run to prep a new SQL Server deployment, get the restored data from the previous installation to see the new installation, hook up SharePoint, etc.

You can use the AT Only wizard to restore a failed AT or build out a TFS farm, but either of these requrie access to data from the original SQL Server deployemnt. If that's still available (and you don't mind leaving the data put), then point the AT Only wizard to the SQL Server where you originally hosted the data and it will "restore" your AT.

Good luck!